# Javascript e SQL - Preencher um boleto com dados de uma linha após seleção da mesma

Tags: javascript, html, sql

Em um site, eu possuo a seguinte função em `Javascript` pra me trazer em uma tabela o resultado de uma consulta `SQL`.

```
function buscaBoletos(){
$.ajax({
    async: false, cache: false,
    url: '[:raiz]emissaoBoletos/getBoletos',
    data: ({
        unidade: $('#comboUnidades').val(),
        de: $('#txtData1').val(),
        ate: $('#txtData2').val()
    }),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#divBoletosLista').hide();
        var retorno = "";
        if (data.length > 0){
            for(var i = 0;i< data.length;i++){
                retorno += "<tr>";
                retorno += "<td style='text-align:left; width:300px'>"+data[i]['razaosocial']+"</td>";
                retorno += "<td style='width: 100px'>"+data[i]['nossonumero']+"</td>";
                retorno += "<td style='width: 80px'>"+data[i]['status']+"</td>";
                retorno += "<td style='width: 80px'>"+data[i]['valor']+"</td>";
                retorno += "<td style='width: 100px'>"+data[i]['dataemissao']+"</td>";
                retorno += "<td style='width: 100px'>"+data[i]['datavencimento']+"</td>";
                retorno += "<td><input class='botaoCad' type='button' value='Visualizar' style='float:none' onclick='verBoleto()'></td>";
                retorno += "</tr>";
            }
        } else {
            retorno = "<tr><td colspan='7' align='center'>"+$('#lblSemRegistros').val()+"</td></tr>";
        }
        $('#bodyBoletosLista').html(retorno);
        $('#divBoletosLista').show();
        $('#divTelaBoleto').hide();
    }
});}
```

Como próximo, passo eu gostaria de poder clicar no botão que é gerado na última coluna da linha (da função `verBoleto()`) e, assim, preencher um boleto (em formato de tabela) com os dados da respectiva linha.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Você conseguiu uma resposta para sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da segunte maneira: pega o id dessa sua consulta e passa como parâmetro da sua função verBoleto();

```
onclick="verBoleto("+ data[i]['id'] +");"
```

Ai na sua função "verBoleto()" você faz uma consulta pelo ID e retorna seu boleto montado somente com essas informações referente ao ID.

Comment: OK, eu mudei o onclick pra onclick='verBoleto("+data[i]['id']+");'. Só preciso configurar melhor a função. Por exemplo, pra eu preencher o campo do boleto Data de Emissão (chamei de dataDoc1 o campo) com o dado da linha (data[i]['dataemissao']), fiz o seguinte: function verBoleto(rowNumber){ $('#dataDoc1').val(data[0]['dataemissao']); } Mas não funcionou. Como eu poderia melhorar isso?

Comment: Poderia coloca o ID ta "tr" e pegar os dados com o parent do jQuery.

Comment: Acho que eu me perdi um pouco aqui. Tu podes colocar isso em código pra eu entender melhor?

Comment: Você pode tirar o id de dentro da função verBoleto() e colocar dentro da sua tr:

<tr id=" + data[i]['id'] + ">

ai você pega as informações do boleto usando parent do jQuery:https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Tipo assim: você vai pegar a informação da td onde o pai dela é a tr do ID = 1; deu pra entender um pouco? Espero estar ajudando e não complicando! kkkk

Comment: Entendi, mas não sei se estou fazendo certo. Agora tentei algo assim pro campo dataDoc1: $("#dataDoc1").val($('#Linha1').find("td").eq(6).html(data[i]['dataemissao']));

Answer (score 0):

Descobri a solução. No onclick da botão Visualizar:

```
onclick='verBoleto("+ data[i]['nossonumero'] +","+ data[i]['valor'] +","+ data[i]['dataemissao'] +","+ data[i]['datavencimento'] +","+ data[i]['razaosocial'] +");'
```

E na função em si, dentro do js:

```
$('#dataDoc1').val(dataemissao);
$('#vencDoc1').val(datavencimento);
$('#sacado1').val(razaosocial);
$('#nossoNum1').val(nossonumero);
$('#valDoc1').val(valor);
```

Por enquanto, consigo preencher pra NossoNumero. Pra Valor eu preencho, mas não pega o número com vírgula direito (170,90 fica só 170). Datas ele transforma num número. E Razão Social nem funciona o Visualizar.

Comment: Você conseguiu uma resposta para sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

vou sugerir algumas mudanças, a primeira é mover o trecho de codigo que monta a linha para outra função, faremos isto para criar uma closure, desta forma ficará mais facil passar os dados para a função verBoleto.

O segundo ponto não tem relação com o problema, mas é uma boa pratica, evite ficar realizando seleção de objetos DOM de forma desnecessaria, faça elas apenas uma vez no inicio no script.

por fim, não declare os seus eventos de forma inline no seu HTML, utilize um EventListener.

```
var bodyBoletosLista = $("#bodyBoletosLista");
var lblSemRegistros = $("#lblSemRegistros");
var divBoletosLista = $('#divBoletosLista');
var divTelaBoleto = $("#divTelaBoleto");
var comboUnidades = $("#comboUnidades");
var txtData1 = $("#txtData1");
var txtData2 = $("#txtData2");

function verBoleto(event, data) {
    console.log(data.razaosocial);
    console.log(data.nossonumero);
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.valor);
    console.log(data.dataemissao);
    console.log(datavencimento);
}

function montarLinha(data) {
    var html = "";
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<td style='text-align:left; width:300px'>" + data.razaosocial + "</td>";
    html += "<td style='width: 100px'>" + data.nossonumero  + "</td>";
    html += "<td style='width: 80px'>" + data.status  + "</td>";
    html += "<td style='width: 80px'>" + data.valor  + "</td>";
    html += "<td style='width: 100px'>" + data.dataemissao  + "</td>";
    html += "<td style='width: 100px'>" + data.datavencimento +"</td>";
    html += "<td><input class='botaoCad' type='button' value='Visualizar' style='float:none'></td>";
    html += "</tr>";

    var linha = $(html);
    var botaoCad = $(".botaoCad", linha);   
    botaoCad.on("click", function (event) {
        verBoleto(event, data);
    })

    bodyBoletosLista.append(linha);
}

function buscaBoletos(){
    $.ajax({
        async: false, cache: false,
        url: '[:raiz]emissaoBoletos/getBoletos',
        data: ({
            unidade: comboUnidades.val(),
            de: txtData1.val(),
            ate: txtData2.val()
        }),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            divBoletosLista.hide(); 

            bodyBoletosLista.html("");              
            if (data.length > 0){
                for(var i = 0;i< data.length;i++){
                    montarLinha(data[i]);
                }
            } else {
                var semRegistros = $("<tr><td colspan='7' align='center'>" + lblSemRegistros.val() + "</td></tr>");
                bodyBoletosLista.append(semRegistros);
            }

            divBoletosLista.show();
            divTelaBoleto.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

opcionalmente, você pode usar uma função de substituição para montar o seu HTML.

**HTML**

```
<template id="tmplBoleto">
    <tr>
        <td style='text-align:left; width:300px'>{razaosocial}</td>
        <td style='width: 100px'>{nossonumero}</td>
        <td style='width: 80px'>{status}</td>
        <td style='width: 80px'>{valor}</td>
        <td style='width: 100px'>{dataemissao}</td>
        <td style='width: 100px'>{datavencimento}</td>
        <td><input class='botaoCad' type='button' value='Visualizar' style='float:none'></td>
    </tr>"
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var tmpl = document.getElementById("tmplBoleto").innerHTML;
var html = tmpl.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(str, prop){
    return data[prop];
});
```